# как сделать ссылку на whatsapp

Tags: android

как сделать ссылку на чат WhatsApp указонному номеру?

Comment: Т.е. нужно сделать  Intent который будет открывать WatsApp с определенным чатом?

Comment: да можете мне помоч?

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean openWhatsAppChat(String phoneNumber) {
    try {
        getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + "+79165025368");
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
    return true;    
}
```

Comment: Великолепный ответ

Comment: `isWhatsappInstalled` изначально будет `false`, так что код в блоке `catch` ни к чему

Comment: И еще у вас нет проверки на установленный маркет :) может быть такое, поверьте, если на устройстве не установлены гапсы. Конечно вы можете забить на нестандартные конфиги юзера, но юзеры есть юзеры :D

Comment: @Flippy  а теперь?

Comment: А так если ватсап не установлен то вылетит

Comment: @Flippy  он же не должен дойти, до отправки intent если watsapp не установлен

Comment: Ах да, не заметил `return`. Но это нормально, если ваш код был представлен как метод)